# TSQL PIVOT Function: Invalid column name error and creating calculated column

Tags: t-sql, pivot, calculated-columns

I'm pretty new to the PIVOT function and I have been trying to figure this out for the past day and a half so I thought I would create an account after lurking for so long and just ask.

I have a table with the layout as follows:

```
AsOfDt      AcctNum MntYr   Dt          Category                Count
4/15/2015   12345   Jan-15  1/18/2015   Registered User         1
4/15/2015   12346   Feb-15  2/7/2015    New Registration User   1
4/15/2015   12347   Jan-15  1/27/2015   Unique Account          1
4/15/2015   12348   Jan-15  1/24/2015   Registered User         1
```

This is the end result I am trying to achieve

```
MntYr        Account Population New Registration User   Registered User Unique Account
Jan 2015     330984             12                      26212           26311
Feb 2015     331897             2953                    58702           58894
Mar 2015     343561             950                     29498           29638
Apr 2015     343181             675                     8845            8916
Grand Total  1349623            4590                    123257          123759
```

Here is the Query that I currently have built:

```
WITH BaseQuery AS (
                SELECT 
                    MntYr
                    ,Category
                    ,[Count]
                FROM [dbo].[rpt_gen_WebPortal_TestingData]
              )

SELECT       [MntYr]
        ,'Account Population'
        ,'Unique Account'
        ,'Registered User'
        ,'New Registration User' 

FROM BaseQuery


pivot (sum([count]) for MntYr  
    in ("Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015", "Apr 2015" )
    ) AS Pivoting
```

My first question:

I am getting an error for my MntYr column in the second SELECT statement, "Invalid column name 'MntYr'." I really don't understand why this is throwing an error. What am I doing wrong with trying to pull that column when I explicitly name it in my BaseQuery pull?

My second question:

I would also like to create a calculated field based upon the percentage of (Unique Account / Account Population), but I'm not quite sure how to go about calculated fields in a PIVOT function. Any ideas on how to get started with this one?

Any and all help would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Right, those are sums of all of the counts per month for each category. If I wasn't to use a pivot how would you suggest going about it?

Comment: It is a pivot, I was just confused by the month/year values in the pivot clause. What is the Account Population?

Comment: It would be another one of the Category types from the table, just wasn't shown in the rows I pulled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pivot clause was wrong. You also don't need a CTE. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    MntYr
    ,[Account Population]
    ,[Unique Account]
    ,[Registered User]
    ,[New Registration User]
    ,case 
        when isnull([Account Population],0) = 0 then 0 
        else 100 * [Unique Account] / [Account Population]
    end Pct
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MntYr
        ,Category
        ,[Count]
    FROM [dbo].[rpt_gen_WebPortal_TestingData]
) BaseQuery
pivot (sum([Count]) for Category
    in ([Account Population]
        ,[Unique Account]
        ,[Registered User]
        ,[New Registration User] )
    ) AS Pivoting
```

Comment: That did it! I really appreciate the help! So do you not have to call the calculated field in the pivot function in clause? I guess that has some part of why I'm a little confused

Comment: Nah, the pivot clause is creating the new columns. You need to do the calculation after that, which is where you see it in the query.

Comment: One last question on this one...If I wanted to have that calculated percentage that we came up with to include 2 decimal places how would you suggest doing that? I currently am getting to the point where I can convert it to a float, but I can't limit the decimal places displayed.

Comment: Easiest way: Replace the `100` with `100.0` to get the float and just format the value in your report or app. If you must do so in the sql you can put the whole calculation inside the `ROUND` function and put that in a `CONVERT`. Something like this: `CONVERT(numeric(10,2),ROUND(100.0 * [Unique Account] / [Account Population],2))`